# How does :_* convert ordered collections into variable arg lists?

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar

I have been using `:_*` to convert `Seq[String]` to `String*` and I realized that I do not understand how this works under the hood.

Is there a simple way to think about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood, `String*` is passed as a `Seq[String]`.  It's all just syntactic sugar:

```
def blah(ss: String*) = {...}
blah("Hi","there")
```

is turned into

```
def blah(ss: Seq[String]) = {...}
blah(Seq("Hi", "there"))
```

and `:_*` just means "hold the sugar, I've already got what you need--a Seq!"

Comment: i.e. it's not a method of Seq, just another sugar - some kind of special operator?  :)

Comment: @tuxSlayer - That's right.  `:` means "is of type", as in `val x: Int` (`x` is of type `Int`).  So `_*` should be some sort of type (the "I know you want varargs but, look here, I've already got a Seq!" type).  Okay, it's not a real type, but at least the sugar is syntactically consistent.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just today I spent some time looking for this method in the library :) Now its clear :)

Comment: Especially with the comments about the "type" _* in the comments, this is quite helpful.